# How to set Navigation text color in Xamarin.Forms when using Shell

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.shell

In my AppShell.xaml I have a number of settings for UI themes.
For example,

```
<Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="Blue" />
<Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
```

However, I can't find the Shell setting for the text which appears next to the <- (Back) button in iOS.
I've tried setting this using the NavigationPage object, but that had no effect.

How can this be set? Thanks.

EDIT: See my own answer/solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

What controls the Back button color is the ForegroundColor setter.

For example:

```
<Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
```